# Homeland - possible "Better Call Saul" series reference

Tags: reference, better-call-saul, homeland

I've recently finished watching the fifth season of [**Homeland**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeland_(TV_series)) whose fifth episode is entitled [**Better Call Saul**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Homeland_episodes#Season_5_.282015.29), which of course is Saul Berenson's first name, one of the main characters of the show played by Mandy Patinkin. But, since the coincidence is so weird, I was wondering if the episode title is also a reference/homage to the [**namesake**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul) series (which is a spin-off of [**Breaking Bad**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad)), although, as far as I'm aware, nothing in the episode's plot seems to allow a connection.

Does anybody have any evidence of the fact that Homeland's fifth episode title was meant as a reference to Vince Gilligan's series?

Comment: The first thought I have is that Alex Gansa and Howard Gordon worked with Vince Gilligan early in their careers on the show The X-Files. Both have gone on to produce high rated cable shows. Maybe they meant it as a shout out to a former coworker.

Comment: I really doubt it is just a coincidence. But It's also not more than a name reference, nothing to do with the events of the episode. I imagine they thought it's clever to name it that since they have a character called *Saul*

Comment: guess, its a decent way of advertisement

Answer (score 8):

It was a two part meaning to the title.
As per the [Wikipedia page on the episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul_(Homeland)#Title)

> The episode title "Better Call Saul" title refers to the necessity of Homeland character Carrie Mathison getting in touch with Saul Berenson and is also a reference to the television series of the same name, which is a spin-off from the series Breaking Bad.

Although a citation is needed, there is [this as well](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4847022/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)