# Origin of Saul Goodman's Name

Tags: character, breaking-bad, better-call-saul

In season one of *[Better Call Saul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul),* we hear James Morgan "Jimmy" McGill, Esq. say "'s all good, man" to another person as a joke. While this seems to be the origin, is it ever hinted at on *[Breaking Bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad)* or known if this was planned all along as the name's origin?

I guess I'm asking if Vince Gilligan or someone else planned this or was it discovered that Saul Goodman could be said/heard as "it's all good, man?" I'm hoping it was mentioned in an interview or commentary or at a convention or something. Do we know? (Either way, it's pretty clever and caught me off guard.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Saul Goodman character made his appearance in **Breaking Bad's Episode 8** of **Season 2** named "**Better Call Saul**". In the "*Insider Podcast*" of the episode, Vince Gilligan explains that he came up with the name "*Saul Goode*" (*it's all good*) one day as he was showering and that it was later changed into "*Saul Goodman*" (*it's all good man*) after the suggestion of one of the other writers, J. Roberts.

Here's the Podcast where Gilligan tells the story (circa 1:25 into the clip):

So, to answer your question, yes, the joke on the name was completely intentional and, while [**in the same episode**](http://www.ibtimes.com/better-call-saul-season-1-spoilers-episode-4-reveals-where-saul-goodman-got-his-name-1825888) of BB Saul explains to Walter that he chose the name in order to sound "*jewish*":

> *“My real name's McGill. The Jew thing I just do for the homeboys. They all want a pipe-hitting member of the tribe, so to speak.”*

in Gilligan's intention the play on words was meant to appeal to the criminal clients that Saul's *law firm* is targeting.

As you pointed out in your question, the "*fictional*" genesis of the name *might be* explained in **Episode 4 Season 1** of **Better Call Saul** ("*Hero*") where a younger James McGill (not yet Esq. and known at the time as "*Slippin Jimmy*"), introduces himself (for the first time?) as “Saul” ... “S’all good, man.”

Comment: Any overlapping with the Homeland series? Season 5 has an episode called Better Call Saul ...

Comment: It might be a [reference](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46045/homeland-possible-better-call-saul-series-reference#comment76773_46045) but that's all I guess ...

Comment: I'm amazed at the patience involved before revealing the joke. YEARS... Thanks, Vince and gang.

Comment: >! **Spoiler** Note that in Better Call Saul ep. **6** of season **3** JMG starts calling himself (in an ad.) SG and gives the (same) reason.